# Toolbar on Inflating Menu Overflow icon Not Visible

Tags: android

I am using Toolbar in place of actionbar.

When I inflate toolbar with a menu

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.id.menu);
```

---

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <item android:id="@+id/action_edit_clinic_details" android:title="@string/action_edit_clinic"
        android:visible="true"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|withText" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_add_new_clinic" android:title="@string/action_add_new_clinic"
        android:visible="true"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|withText" />
</menu>
```

Menu in toolbar gets inflated. But the three dot button (pipe) is not visible.

But when I click in the place of overflow icon it shows the menu items.
Actually the menu icons are some how not visible but clickable.

How to make menu pipe icon visible?

Comment: What if you inflate it inside `onCreateOptionsMenu`?

Comment: then i have to set getActivity().setActionBar(toolbar); first that i do not want to do

Comment: False alarm, it was due to my toolbar background color and textColorSecondary were of same color. :(